# Ticks unevenly spread-out

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image: Adjacency Matrix]

I am plotting an adjacency matrix representing neurons connections but the spacing between ticks on both axes are not consistent. Some ticks are so close to each other's that their label overlap and other ticks are very spread apart creating large gaps.

About the data:

The data is in a dataframe where the first column contains Source and the second column contains Target. Every entry in this dataframe is a character.

Here is how the data look like:

```
Source Target

RID    ALA

ADLL   ADLR

AFDL   AFDR

AFDL   AIBL

AVAL   AS01

AVAL   AS06
```

targetOrder is a factor made of the column Source

```
    targetOrder

    RID

    ADLL   

    AFDL   

    AFDL  

    AVAL

    AVAL
```

More details on what is going on:

The x-axis and the y-axis are discrete, similar (containing the same values) and in the same order. Both axes contain 80 neurons. The neuron on the y-axis shoots at a neuron on the x-axis creating a dot where they intersect.

Here is the code I am using:

```
ggplot(data = dataFrame)+           
  geom_point(mapping = aes (x = Target, y = Source), color = "#0000FF")+
  labs(title="Adjacency Matrix")+
  scale_x_discrete(limits = targetOrder)+   #Target oder used on both axis
  scale_y_discrete(limits = targetOrder)+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 0, vjust = 0))
  theme(axis.ticks.length = unit(.5, "cm"))
```

I have spent the last few days looking for answers to this question but could not find any. In the process, I learned everything else about ticks, like how to customize their sizes...

If you need any other informations just ask and I will do my best.

Comment: Can you give an example of the `targetOrder` variable? We don't have it so we can't reproduce your example.

Comment: Without data to replicate your problem, we can't help you much. Do you observe this behavior also if you select, say, only ten sources / targets?

Comment: ☺☺☺ I FIGURED IT OUT !!! ☺☺☺



Hello everyone !!!





So there is repetition in the ticks name so only the first one would appear.
Example: ABAAC will be displayed as AB__C
In other words, any tick name can only once on an axis which kinda makes sense ^^



Thank you very much for your attention and I wish you a great summer !!! ☺☺